# Why does my count/n parameter limit to 100 for api.search_tweets in tweepy?

Tags: python, database, twitter, tweepy

I want to get at least 10,000 of the most recent tweets containing the word 'bitcoin' using tweepy. I checked the parameters, and people online are saying the number of tweets (count) that tweepy's api.search_tweets() can be up to 18,000... but when i use 10,000 as the count it only returns a list of the 100 most recent tweets. I attached some code below to check out. Lemme know if anyone knows an answer to this.

```
# setting my query
search_term = "bitcoin -filter:retweets"
# making a list of all tweets with my query
search_tweets = api.search_tweets(q = search_term, lang = "en", count = 10000)

# shows me how many tweets api.search_tweets() gets
print(f"Number of tweets found: {len(search_tweets)}")

# loops through each tweet in search_tweets and prints information about each tweet
for tweet in search_tweets:
    print(f"{tweet.user.name} tweeted: ")
    print(tweet.text)
    print(f"# of likes: {tweet.favorite_count}")
    print(f'# of retweets: {tweet.retweet_count}')
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------") #seperates each tweet
```

this outputs this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHQuV.png

You can see it works, but we still only get a list of 100 tweets when my count is 18,000...

Answer (score 1):

Use **tweepy's cursor** object get more than 100 tweets.

Here's an example:

```
n=500

tweets=tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,q="#bitcoin",lang="en",tweet_mode="extended").items(n)


tweets_json=[]
for tweet in tweets:
   tweets_json.append(tweet._json)
```

This will return a list which contains the tweet info in json format.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the documentation?  That request is limited to 100 at a time.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

```
count   optional    The number of tweets to return per page, up to a maximum of 100. Defaults to 15. This was formerly the "rpp" parameter in the old Search API.       100
```

Comment: Oh!! I guess I misread it.. it says 100 per page, do you know how I can do multiple pages then?

Comment: Nope.  You can try adding "page=2" as an experiment, but that's just a guess.  The documentation doesn't describe that.